# How do some deep sea creatures lower their metabolism to stay alive for a long time?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, health, lifespan

I was watching some bio related videos and saw in one that some deep sea creatures  and other organisms purposefully limit their movement to decrease metabolism rates. Do they live longer?

If we apply this same theory to humans, doesn't it mean that exercising less and regulation of diet may help decrease metabolic rates? I know exercise is extremely good for the body but this just got me thinking...